# Can I return value found in this any iteration?

Tags: python, loops

I'm teaching myself python and I'm making some changes to a bot that someone else wrote.

I'm trying to add a filter for words that NSFW or not kid friendly. I've added these words to a list called config.banned_name_keywords.

I had it working originally by returning the whole tweet, but I'm trying to return the SPECIFIC word that was found so I can troubleshoot and edit the list.

I can return the whole tweet with tweet.text but that takes away from the output and clogs up the screen.

I've also tried print(x) but I can't tell where that's being defined. It's returning the word that found the tweet in the first place.

```py
for tweet in searched_tweets:
    if any(rtwords in tweet.text.lower().split() for rtwords in config.retweet_tags):
        # The script only cares about contests that require retweeting. It would be very weird to not have to
        # retweet anything; that usually means that there's a link  you gotta open and then fill up a form.
        # This clause checks if the text contains any retweet_tags
        if tweet.retweeted_status is not None:
            # In case it is a retweet, we switch to the original one
            if any(y in tweet.retweeted_status.text.lower().split() for y in config.retweet_tags):
                tweet = tweet.retweeted_status
            else:
                continue
        if tweet.user.screen_name.lower() in config.banned_users or any(x in tweet.user.name.lower() for x in config.banned_name_keywords):
            # If it's the original one, we check if the author is banned
            print("Avoided user with ID: " + tweet.user.screen_name + " & Name: " + tweet.user.name)
            continue
        elif any(z in tweet.text.lower().split() for z in config.banned_name_keywords):
            # If the author isn't banned, we check for words we don't want
            print("Avoided tweet with words:" + z)
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Not now, but you will be able to in Python 3.8 via [assignment expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
elif any((caught := z) in tweet.text.lower().split() for z in config.banned_name_keywords):
    print("Avoided tweet with word: " + caught)
```

If you want to catch *all* the banned words that might appear, you can't use `any`, since its purpose is to stop as soon as you find one match. For this, you just want to compute the intersection instead (which you can do today as well):

```
banned = set(config.banned_name_keywords)

...

else:
    caught = banned.intersection(tweet.text.lower().split())
    if caught:
        print("Avoided tweet with banned words: " + caught)
```

(That itself can be shortened using assignment expressions as well:

```
elif (caught := banned.intersection(tweet.text.lower().split())):
    print("Avoided tweet with banned words: " + caught)
```

)

Comment: is `:=` valid in python 3.5?

Comment: Can you show me what this would look like in the context of the above code? Does the variable get defined inside the loop?

Comment: Show you what *what* would look like? The first code block is how you would use `:=` once a version of Python that supports it is released; the second version works now in any version of Python released in the last 10 or 15 years; the third is a Python 3.8+-specific version of the second.

Comment: You're right. I have some indentation and space/tabs errors. This works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
if tweet.user.screen_name.lower() in config.banned_users or any(x in tweet.user.name.lower() for x in config.banned_name_keywords):
```

to

```
try:
    # matched_banned_keyword below is the `SPECIFIC` word that matched
    matched_banned_keyword = config.banned_name_keywords[config.banned_name_keywords.index(tweet.user.name.lower())] 
except:
    matched_banned_keyword = None
if tweet.user.screen_name.lower() in config.banned_users or matched_banned_keyword:
    print("Avoided user with ID: " + tweet.user.screen_name + " & Name: " + tweet.user.name)
```

`L.index(x)` function returns the index of the `x` in the list `L` and raises an exception if `x` is not present in the list `L`. You can catch the exception which will occur in your case when `user.screen_name.lower()` is not present in `config.banned_name_keywords`